# List with Multiple Lines With Multiple Level

Tags: jquery-ui, listview, css, jquery-mobile

I have three level data in my page and on the first level I need to display multiline data.

When I have only one level the multiline works perfect. so the following code works well.

```
 <ul data-role="listview" 
     data-theme="a" data-inset="true" data-dividertheme="c" data-counttheme="e">
            <li>
                <h3><a href="">Paris (CDG) to Munich (MUC)</a></h3>
                <h4>150 EUR</h4>
                <p>12:50 to 14:15 (1h25) Direct</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3><a href="">Paris (CDG) to Munich (MUC)</a></h3>
                <h4>175 EUR</h4>
                <p>15:00 to 16:15 (1h15) Direct</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3><a href="">Paris (CDG) to Munich (MUC)</a></h3>
                <h4>225 EUR</h4>
                <p>16:00 to 20:00 (4h) wait 2h Frankfurt, Germany</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And show perfect result.

[image]

But when I add few UL to show nested stuff the things started breaking.

I put following lines.

```
     <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-inset="true" data-dividertheme="c" data-counttheme="e">
            <li>
                <h3><a href="">Paris (CDG) to Munich (MUC)</a></h3>
                <h4>150 EUR</h4>
                <p>12:50 to 14:15 (1h25) Direct</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">View</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reset</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
           </UL>
```

And it starts breaking. And give result like following.[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try below link and check whether you are using proper syntax or not, it may be possible you are not using code pattern which is present in jquery mobile or Jquery mobile understandable code.

Link: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html#/test/docs/lists/lists-nested.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nesting `<ul>` tags in a jQM list view as a direct child does not work. It looks like something in the jQuery Mobile framework removes those from list views.

You can, however, wrap your child `<ul>` tags with a `<div>`, that works and can still be styled to your liking.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/MVt2B/